# How use debug in Eclipse correctly?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I know this could sound as a 'very easy' question, but I really don't understand or found anywhere, how to use the debugger in a Java EE (JSF) application correctly.
I mean:

```
1. open eclipse
2. insert a break point at code
3. click into the 'bug' button 
4. glassfish starts
5. interact into the web site until the break point is activated, right?
```

Wrong.
Nothing happens.. And I tried many different ways and it seems not to be working at all.
So I wonder if you guys could me explain how to do it (and I swear I will paint the instructions into the wall =] )

Comment: Are you starting an Eclipse integrated Server environment for Glassfish?  Is your web project Added to the Server as a module?  Did you right click the Server icon from the Servers view and select `Start in Debug`?  After the server started do your breakpoints display with a check mark over them (signifying that the breakpoint was properly loaded)?

Comment: @maple_shaft, the answer of Serkan works for me, and yours too, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project, Debug As -> Debug on Server (Alt+Shift+D, R)

or press the pull down menu next to 'bug' button, and follow the same menu order.

Comment: I did what you told and it works. But why sometimes the Variables tab, appears empty at Eclipse ?